# convert array to simple xml

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

this is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tab_id] => 351
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tab_name] => test1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [region_timezone] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [registrationstatus] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [eventstatus] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [dist_activity] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 10068
                    [2] => 10070
                )

            [dist_region] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5069
                    [1] => 5069
                    [2] => 5069
                )

            [dist_value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 55
                    [1] => 342
                    [2] => 86
                )

            [dist_unit] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                )

            [dist_map] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                )

            [entryfee_currency] => Array
                (
                    [0] => USD
                )

            [reg_str_dt] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-01-14 20:35:00
                )

            [reg_end_dt] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-01-14 20:35:00
                )

            [individual_label] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 19+++
                )

            [individual_born_from] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1980-08-21
                )

            [individual_born_to] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2010-08-18
                )

            [individual_sex] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                )

            [individual_strdt] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-01-14 20:35:00
                )

            [individual_start] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-01-14 20:35:00
                )

            [elite_sex] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tab_id] => 352
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tab_name] => test2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [region_timezone] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [registrationstatus] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [eventstatus] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [dist_activity] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 10069
                    [2] => 10070
                )

            [dist_region] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4457
                    [1] => 7140
                    [2] => 5069
                )

            [dist_value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 55
                    [1] => 213
                    [2] => 86
                )

            [dist_unit] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                )

            [dist_map] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                )

            [entryfee_currency] => Array
                (
                    [0] => USD
                )

            [reg_str_dt] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-02-14 20:39:00
                )

            [reg_end_dt] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-02-14 20:39:00
                )

            [individual_label] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 19+++
                )

            [individual_born_from] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1980-08-21
                )

            [individual_born_to] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2010-08-18
                )

            [individual_sex] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                )

            [individual_strdt] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-02-14 20:39:00
                )

            [individual_start] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-02-14 20:39:00
                )

            [elite_sex] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

How can I convert an array to a SimpleXML object in PHP?
I want to display this array as xml (convert into xml)
please help me out of this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert array to SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml)

Answer (score 0):

say  your array is `$data`

try this

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($data, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ArrayToXML
{
    /**
     * The main function for converting to an XML document.
     * Pass in a multi dimensional array and this recrusively loops through and builds up an XML document.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @param string $rootNodeName - what you want the root node to be - defaultsto data.
     * @param SimpleXMLElement $xml - should only be used recursively
     * @return string XML
     */
    public static function toXml($data, $rootNodeName = 'data', $xml=null)
    {
        // turn off compatibility mode as simple xml throws a wobbly if you don't.
        if (ini_get('zend.ze1_compatibility_mode') == 1)
        {
            ini_set ('zend.ze1_compatibility_mode', 0);
        }

        if ($xml == null)
        {
            $xml = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><$rootNodeName />");
        }

        // loop through the data passed in.
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            // no numeric keys in our xml please!
            if (is_numeric($key))
            {
                // make string key...
                $key = "unknownNode_". (string) $key;
            }

            // replace anything not alpha numeric
            $key = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $key);

            // if there is another array found recrusively call this function
            if (is_array($value))
            {
                $node = $xml->addChild($key);
                // recrusive call.
                ArrayToXML::toXml($value, $rootNodeName, $node);
            }
            else 
            {
                // add single node.
                                $value = htmlentities($value);
                $xml->addChild($key,$value);
            }

        }
        // pass back as string. or simple xml object if you want!
        return $xml->asXML();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class array2xml
{
    $output = "";
    function array2xml($array, $root = 'root', $element = 'element')
    {
        $this->output .= $this->make($array, $root, $element);
    }

    function make($array, $root, $element)
    {
        $xml = "<{$root}>\n";
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $xml .= $this->make($value, $element, $key);
            } else {
                if (is_numeric($key)) {
                    $xml .= "<{$root}>{$value}</{$root}>\n";
                } else {
                    $xml .= "<{$key}>{$value}</{$key}>\n";
                }
            }
        }
        $xml .= "</{$root}>\n";
        return $xml;
    }
}

echo "After convertion from array to xml format <br />";
echo array2xml($output_array);
```